# how to make Toolbar overlaying in CN1?

Tags: codenameone

Since the `Form` ,where a content pane and the toolbar is part of, has a `LayeredLayout` I tried to set insets of each container appropriately to manage this but it doesn't seem to work. Is it possible in a form at all?

```
val l = layout as LayeredLayout
l.setInsets(toolbar, "0 0 auto 0")
     .setInsets(contentPane, "0")
     .setReferenceComponentTop(contentPane, null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `Toolbar` floating on top effect you need to construct it differently. This places it in the forms layered pane which floats above everything. You can't set the layout above the content pane to something else as this is a hidden implementation detail.

If global toolbar is enabled you can just override this method in `Form`:

```
protected void initGlobalToolbar() {
    setToolbar(new Toolbar(true));
}
```

Otherwise you can just use the `setToolbar(new Toolbar(true));` to create a floating toolbar.